# Addthis button size class stopped working

Tags: addthis

We have a sharing toolbox that defaults to 32x32 px but we also use the same toolbox code to display at 20x20 px in other parts of our site. The code below (including Drupal tokens) worked fine for a few months but last month it started showing the icons at 32x32 even though it has the class `addthis_20x20_style`. It also changed the behavior on another system outside Drupal that uses the same toolbox code.

```
<div addthis:title="[node:title]" addthis:url="[node:url]" 
class="addthis_sharing_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_20x20_style">
&nbsp;</div>
```

I tried changing `addthis_sharing_toolbox` to `addthis_toolbox` per the support page at http://www.addthis.com/academy/customizing-the-addthis-toolbox/, but then the buttons do not display at all. The AddThis support pages are incredibly disorganized and outdated and they seem to have abandoned their user forum. I don't even know where else to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reply I received from AddThis support. Hopefully this will be of use to others:

> JAN 07, 2016  |  03:26PM EST
>
> Hi,
>
> We recently made a change to our code that affected some of our older
>   buttons.
>
> You will need to use our advanced configuration code in the locations
>   that you would like our buttons to appear in 20x20.
>
> Replace the current code in these locations with the following:
>
> ```
> <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_20x20_style">
> <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
> <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
> <a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
> <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
> <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
> </div>
> ```
>
> Additional advanced configuration code information can be found here:
>
> http://www.addthis.com/academy/customizing-the-addthis-toolbox/
>
> Please let me know if you need any additional help
>
> Thanks,
>
> Mike

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. You must just replace "preferred_x" to name of a social network

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem.  It looks like they have removed support for 20x20 sized buttons, as it is no longer listed on the academy support page you provided.  It is a shame because it is the only size that has a constant height for facebook, facebook_like, tweet, etc buttons.

The below css styles, while feeling a little hacky, go some distance in repairing the broken functionality:

```
.addthis_20x20_style .at-icon-wrapper,
.addthis_20x20_style .at-icon {
    height:20px !important;
    width:20px !important;
}
```

That didn't fix the size of the google_plusone button.  I happen to be using drupal as well - the addthis module - and the below 'customize services' settings worked pretty well.

[image]

That's:

- Service code: google_plusone
- HTML classes: addthis_button_google_plusone
- HTML attributes: g:plusone:size="medium"

(Re the addthis service, the phrase "you had one job!" comes to mind...)

Comment: Thanks, I've been corresponding with their support team about the fact that the 20x20 code they provided now produces 16x16 buttons.   

Hard to understand why they would remove this option. I agree with you that the workarounds are getting so hacky that it starts to defeat the purpose of using their service (since we don't find the stats very useful either).